# How do we use julia to read through each character of a .txt file, one at a time?

Tags: file, io, character, julia

I am trying to go through a .txt file with Julia, and I need to be able to look at every character as the program reads through the file. What little I have found on the Julia Docs page is how to read line by line. I know that the basic set up should be something like this

```
file = open("testfile.txt","r");
while !eof(file)
    //look at each character and store it to a variable
```

Once it is stored into a variable I know how to manipulate it, but I can't figure out how to get it into the variable storage.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `read` function like this:

```
file = open("testfile.txt","r")
while !eof(file)
    c = read(file, Char)
    # your stuff
end
close(file)
```

This will read it character by character using UTF-8.

If you want to read it byte by byte then use:

```
file = open("testfile.txt","r")
while !eof(file)
    i = read(file, UInt8)
    # your stuff
end
close(file)
```

Note that you can use `do` block to automatically close a file when you leave it:

```
open("testfile.txt","r") do file
    while !eof(file)
        i = read(file, UInt8)
        # your stuff
    end
end
```

For a more complete example you might want to have look e.g. at this function https://github.com/bkamins/Nanocsv.jl/blob/master/src/csvreader.jl#L1 that uses pattern `read(io, Char)` to parse CSV files.

Comment: Thanks for the help. This was what I needed. I saw this in the help, but didn't realize that char had to be written as **Char** to be correctly passed.

Comment: @NoahFranck The above answer looks great.  Why not accept it so the person who took the time to write it gets the credit that acceptance gives?

Comment: @JuliaLearner I honestly didn't know that there was an option to select an answer or mark that it was most beneficial until you mentioned it.

Comment: @NoahFranck Thanks for noticing.  I noticed another one as well [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52339092/julia-passing-arguments-reading-the-command-line/52437448#52437448) you might consider checking.

Comment: See also this Q&A for reading a file by lines: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58169711/how-to-read-a-file-line-by-line-in-julia/58169712