# Julia passing arguments, reading the command line

Tags: input, julia

I am trying to prompt the user of my .jl file to enter user entered multiple destinations.

Basically I need the user to give an input & an output. I know in java you would use a scanner, or accept arguments when it is compiled in the command line. I am fine with either option. From what I have found looking through the Julia Documentation I think I could accomplish the first way of assigning a variable to the readline function.

```
(String)in = (String)Readline(STDIN)
```

From my understanding the variable 'in' should now contain a String of the user's input. I am encountering an error, in that when I compile my .jl code, because my command prompt does not stop to read user input, and just finishes reading the .jl code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first item to note in the code in your question is:

```
(String)in = (String)Readline(STDIN)
```

Julia 1.0.0 now uses `stdin` instead of `STDIN`.

Next, the `(String)` typecasting is not something you need or want to do in Julia.

Thus your code could read (though we get an error):

```
julia> in = readline(stdin)
This is a test.
ERROR: cannot assign variable Base.in from module Main
```

So variable `in` is in conflict with a Julia `Base.in` variable.  Just use a another variable name.

```
julia> response = readline(stdin)
This is a test.
"This is a test"
```

This code is now working, but it has no prompt.  Your answer provides an example input function with a prompt which you defined like this:

```
julia> function input(prompt::AbstractString="")
           print(prompt)
           return chomp(readline())
       end
input (generic function with 2 methods)
```

The `chomp` function removes a single trailing `\n` newline character from the input string.  Docs [here](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/strings/#Base.chomp).

Example use of the function here:

```
julia> input_file = input("Please enter input file name: ")
Please enter input file name: Data.txt
"Data.txt"

julia> output_file = input("Please enter output file name: ")
Please enter output file name: Output.txt
"Output.txt"
```

**Command Line Args Method**

As the [docs](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/#man-getting-started-1) point out, to just print out the arguments given to a script, you can do something like this:

```
println("Arguments passed to ", PROGRAM_FILE, ":")
for arg in ARGS
    println(arg)
end
```

Here is an example of above code running on the Windows command line:

```
c:\OS_Prompt>julia PrintArgs.jl Data.txt Output1.txt Output2.txt Output3.txt
Arguments passed to PrintArgs.jl:
Data.txt
Output1.txt
Output2.txt
Output3.txt
```

You can also print out the script file name as shown, PrintArgs.jl.

Comment: @Noah Does the above  adequately answer your questions?

Comment: @Noah If the above answers your question, you might consider accepting it by clicking the check mark.  Note that you will get SO reputation points, 2, and I also get SO rep points, 15 [see](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

After searching & testing I found one solution and decided to reply to it here. I had to declare my own function to be able to get the program to accept user input.

```
function input(prompt::AbstractString="")
    print(prompt)
    return chomp(readline())
end
```

I am not sure what the chomp function does, but I know it works for what I was asking. I am still curious if you can do something in Julia similar to java and C String args[], in which you pass extra information while you are telling your command to run. Something like the following.

```
Julia testFile.jl goHere.txt lookHere.txt
```

Comment: there is an `ARGS` in Julia and [the first chapter of the manual](https://docs.julialang.org/en/latest/manual/getting-started/#man-getting-started-1) has a concise example on how to use it.