# How to read a file line by line in Julia?

Tags: file-io, julia

How do I open a text file and read it line by line? There are two different cases I'm interested in answers for:

1. Get all the lines in an array at once.
2. Process each line one at a time.

For the second case I don't want to have to keep all the lines in memory at one time.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Reading a file into memory all at once as an array of lines is just a call to the `readlines` function:

```
julia> words = readlines("/usr/share/dict/words")
235886-element Array{String,1}:
 "A"
 "a"
 "aa"
 ⋮
 "zythum"
 "Zyzomys"
 "Zyzzogeton"
```

By default this discards the newlines but if you want to keep them, you can pass the keyword argument `keep=true`:

```
julia> words = readlines("/usr/share/dict/words", keep=true)
235886-element Array{String,1}:
 "A\n"
 "a\n"
 "aa\n"
 ⋮
 "zythum\n"
 "Zyzomys\n"
 "Zyzzogeton\n"
```

If you have an already opened file object you can also pass that to the `readlines` function:

```
julia> open("/usr/share/dict/words") do io
           readline(io) # throw out the first line
           readlines(io)
       end
235885-element Array{String,1}:
 "a"
 "aa"
 "aal"
 ⋮
 "zythum"
 "Zyzomys"
 "Zyzzogeton"
```

This demonstrates the `readline` function, which reads a single line from an open I/O object, or when given a file name, opens the file and reads the first line from it:

```
julia> readline("/usr/share/dict/words")
"A"
```

If you don't want to load the file contents all at once (or if you're processing streaming data like from a network socket), then you can use the `eachline` function to get an iterator that produces lines one at a time:

```
julia> for word in eachline("/usr/share/dict/words")
           if length(word) >= 24
               println(word)
           end
       end
formaldehydesulphoxylate
pathologicopsychological
scientificophilosophical
tetraiodophenolphthalein
thyroparathyroidectomize
```

The `eachline` function can, like `readlines`, also be given an opened file handle to read lines from. You can also "roll your own" iterator by opening the file and calling `readline` repeatedly:

```
julia> open("/usr/share/dict/words") do io
           while !eof(io)
               word = readline(io)
               if length(word) >= 24
                   println(word)
               end
           end
       end
formaldehydesulphoxylate
pathologicopsychological
scientificophilosophical
tetraiodophenolphthalein
thyroparathyroidectomize
```

This is equivalent to what `eachline` does for you and it's rare to need to do this yourself but if you need to, the ability is there. For more information about reading a file character by character, see this question and answer: [How do we use julia to read through each character of a .txt file, one at a time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52281241/how-do-we-use-julia-to-read-through-each-character-of-a-txt-file-one-at-a-time)